# How can I restore an OEM hidden disk partition (PQSERVICE) on disk0?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, hard-drive-recovery, partition-recovery, system-reserved-partition

Acer Aspire 4720Z Laptop, Windows Vista SP2:

I have a 111.79MB SATA/AHCI hard disk with the following partitions:

[image]

The first partition, used for Recovery, originally had a logical name of PQSERVICE, but the name mysteriously disappeared and is also totally empty!

However, when I boot this laptop, it does a real fast `CHKNTFS` on volume label {60df5556-b5f8-11dd-9ca2-806e6f6e6963}, which corresponds to the empty 9.76GB partition with no logical name.

I executed diskpart.exe to obtain more detailed info.

QUESTIONS: Based on the info you see below, should I attempt to re-establish the PQSERVICE logical name to hopefully get Recovery working again?.. If Recovery got toasted, should I delete the partition so I can expand drive C: another 10GB's, or just leave everything as is and tell CHKNTFS to stop checking that partition?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It looks like the data is already gone.

Comment: So is it safe to delete this partition?

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain why you downvoted?

Comment: The data has been wiped, there is nothing to lose, if you were to wipe the partition.

Comment: OK, so the data is gone.. I'm asking whether I can re-establish the recovery mechanism by adding logical name PQSERVICE to that partition.

Comment: The data is not necessarily gone...

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to run something like TestDisk to inspect whether there is still actual data around, from there you can attempt to get the partition to see its MBR back. This assumes no bits were overwritten and that only the partition information was affected.

If however the actual partition data has been corrupted as well, there is nothing you can do...